# Mongoose - populate nested array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs

I have done e-commerce store and I would like to populate product in orderProduct array. Currently I do like this:

```
.populate({
          path: 'orderedProductArray',
          populate: {
            path: '0',
            populate: {
              path: 'product',
              model: 'Cloth'
            }
          }
        })
```

[image]

The problem is that I am not able to populate all objects included in orderProduct Array. Do you have any idea how can I adjust this? Thanks in advance!